# CSV Output from largely populated HashMap

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

I have a hashmap that stores values of various latitude and longitudes as well as other attributes. I want to print them out based on the user's input variable called `interval`. The bigger the interval is, the bigger the hashmap. My problem is, the maximum interval I can hit at the moment is 300, to generate a complete csv file. When I input 400, the excel file cannot be loaded completely, and what's more I need the interval to be set at 500. When I set it at 500, this is the error I get,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
```

I looked it up and apparently it's because the output is copied to an array first which is not able to support so much data. Is there a way I can break up my HashMap, and then combine then print them into a csv?

```
FileWriter writer= null;
        String output = "";
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter("output.csv");
            writer.write("Name,Latitude,Longitude,Distance");
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (Entry<String, LocationPoint> entry : locationHash.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Location lp = entry.getValue();

                double lat = lp.getLatitude();
                double lng = lp.getLongtitude();
                double dist = lp.getDistance();
                String name= "";

                String pName = lp.getPointName();
                if (pName.contains("nearStation") || pName.contains("nearLine")) {
                    name = pName.split("_")[1];
                } else
                    name = pName.split("_")[0];
                //
                builder.append(name);
                builder.append(",");
                builder.append(String.valueOf(lat));
                builder.append(",");
                builder.append(String.valueOf(lng));
                builder.append(",");
                builder.append(String.valueOf(dist));
                builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            }
            output = builder.toString();
            mrtWriter.write(output);
            System.out.println("Output Complete");

        } finally {
            if (mrtWriter != null) {
                mrtWriter.close();
            }
        }
```

** LocationHash stores a string for the key, and a Location object for the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this because your StringBuilder is growing larger than the maximum length of an integer (Integer.MAX_VALUE). This is the maximum number for an array and trying to expand it over this limit raises the exception you just got.

To solve this you can simply write directly into the `mrtWriter` object. For performance, wrap it into a BufferedWriter:

```
 Writer mrtWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("path/to/file")));
```

If you want to keep the StringBuilder for some reason, then append a few lines in your StringBuilder, then call `mrtWriter.write(builder.toString())`, followed by `output.setLength(0)` to reset  the StringBuilder.

Comment: Or, if you use it for buffering, use a BufferedWriter

Comment: Thanks! I decided there wasn't a use for my stringbuilder. You da man cheers